# Updating a zip file using UpdateableZipFile code given by Or Weis

Tags: python, zip, php-ziparchive, file-writing

I am new to Python but not to programming. I am trying to replace a file in a zip archive with another  using the code for **UpdateableZipFile** given by Or Weis but I am not getting it right. Here is the relevant code:

```py
testzip = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test.zip' with UpdateableZipFile(testzip, "a") as o:
    o.write(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Keep VSKP tkt.pdf','Cancel VSKP tkt.pdf')
```

When I run this using Python 3.8, the zip file remains the same. A new folder is created on Desktop with these subfolders:

```
 \Users\user\Desktop\Keep VSKP tkt.pdf
```

What is wrong?